# Place Pixijs Particles Around Object Inside Png Image

Tags: javascript, png, object-detection, pixi.js

I've found this spark particle example on PixiJS particles editor: https://pixijs.io/pixi-particles-editor/#sparks

Now what I want to achieve is to Place these particles around the object inside the transparent png image.
Check the image below to understand better.

[image: Image of what I want to achieve]

**Alternatively, If we skip the object detection part, How can we place these particles on a user-defined path?**
Something like this 
[image: Alternate question if object detection is tough]

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer solves your problem.

first, you draw the outline and save only the outline as an image

[image: draw over the image]

[image: outline image look like this]

now convert the image to base64
[this site will help you to convert to base64](https://www.base64-image.de/)

now you can change the outline image to particles as a refernce

```js
// Tamino Martinius - All rights reserved

// Copyright © 2013 Tamino Martinius (http://zaku.eu)
// Copyright © 2013 Particleslider.com (http://particleslider.com

// Terms of usage: http://particleslider.com/legal/license

var init = function(){
  var isMobile = navigator.userAgent &&
    navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile') >= 0;
  var isSmall = window.innerWidth < 1000;
  
  var ps = new ParticleSlider({
    ptlGap: isMobile || isSmall ? 3 : 0,
    ptlSize: isMobile || isSmall ? 3 : 1,
    width: 1e9,
    height: 1e9
  });
    
  var gui = new dat.GUI();
  gui.add(ps, 'ptlGap').min(0).max(5).step(1).onChange(function(){
    ps.init(true);
  });
  gui.add(ps, 'ptlSize').min(1).max(5).step(1).onChange(function(){
    ps.init(true);
  });
  gui.add(ps, 'restless');
  gui.addColor(ps, 'color').onChange(function(value){
    ps.monochrome = true;
    ps.setColor(value);
      ps.init(true);
  });
  
  
  (window.addEventListener
   ? window.addEventListener('click', function(){ps.init(true)}, false)
   : window.onclick = function(){ps.init(true)});
}

var initParticleSlider = function(){
  var psScript = document.createElement('script');
  (psScript.addEventListener
    ? psScript.addEventListener('load', init, false)
    : psScript.onload = init);
  psScript.src = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/23500/ps-0.9.js';
    psScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  document.body.appendChild(psScript);
}
    
(window.addEventListener
  ? window.addEventListener('load', initParticleSlider, false)
  : window.onload = initParticleSlider);
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  .slides, & > .dg {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    background-position:center;
    background-image: url('https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.com-audiaudicarluxurious-carprofessional-carwhite-audired-audi-1701527409582ukddw.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
    & > .dg {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ParticleSlider</title>
  </head>
  <body id="particle-slider">
      <div class="slides">
        <div id="first-slide" class="slide" data-src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        </div>
        </div>
        <canvas class="draw"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

[For more Codepen link for example](https://codepen.io/aashifahamed/pen/yLMzaJg)

Final result

[image: Final reslut]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts into this Aashif, Your answer conceptually solves my problem so upvoting and awarding the bounty . 
I will accept this answer as soon as this works in the implementation concerning my question.